# Flexible low level http library for Java?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, squid, purge

I trying to purge caches on [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and in order to do it I need to execute weird http request.

Request should look like:

```
PURGE www.cached:port/params HTTP/1.1
```

where `www.cached:port/params` represents value I want to remove from cache.

So, here is the interesting thing - connection should be opened to a squid server, not to `www.cached:port/params`.

So, whole sequence will be:

1. open connection to a squid server.
2. pass `PURGE` request.
3. read results.
4. close

I tried apache httpclient. I can rewrite request method to make it send `PURGE`, but library always opens connection against same host it passes in a http request (open connection to `www.cached`, do a `PURGE` `www.cached`) and it just doesn't work for me.

I can do it by using pure sockets, but it  will be great to find a library that just works.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://netty.io/ ?

Comment: It could work. I can override toString on  DefaultHttpRequest. Will try to do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I see no reason why this could not be done with Apache HttpClient. Did you configure the client to execute requests via a proxy using 'http.route.default-proxy' parameter?

Anyway, if you do not mind using lower components this is how the same can be done with Apache HttpCore (blocking)

```
    HttpProcessor httpproc = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(new HttpRequestInterceptor[] {
            new RequestContent(),
            new RequestTargetHost(),
            new RequestConnControl(),
            new RequestUserAgent()});

    HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
    ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy();

    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.cached", port);
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("squid", 8080);

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("PURGE", "www.cached:port/params");

    DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
    try {
        if (!conn.isOpen()) {
            Socket socket = new Socket(proxy.getHostName(), proxy.getPort());
            conn.bind(socket, params);
        }
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, target);

        httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, context);
        HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, context);
        httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, context);

        // do something useful with the response

        if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, context)) {
            conn.close();
        } else {
            // Connection could be kept alive
        }
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I am sure the same is very doable with other HTTP libraries